Culture of conferences and registration fees
In some countries (EU?) registration fees have to be paid in advance, online only and nonrefundable, while in other countries participation can be decided at the last minute and registration fees can always be paid onsite. In the former conference fees are usually higher and don't even include meals, but in the latter they are cheaper and always include meals each day.  It appears that those who insist on receiving registration fees in advance show too strong an indication of earning money? What is the dynamics and mechanism of this cultural thing behind all this?

I don't think there are general rules for this in any country. I have attended a large number of conferences in several EU countries and have met all kinds of different things in each of the countries in which I visited enough conferences. Rather obviously, this thing is not uniform within any country, so you shouldn't suggest it is. It may be possible to find statistical differences in this respect between countries, but that's probably because some people just copy what has happened in other conferences they know, often in the same country.

I agree with xLeitx, these "norms" are totally foreign to me. My conferences rarely have meals, and I've never paid on site (usually because it's much more expensive). Perhaps, name a field?

This does not match my experience. All of the conferences I've ever attended required advanced registration (especially for any accepted papers; at least one author must register), and discounts for early-bird registration. The offered 'refreshments' varied from just tea and coffee, small snacks, one full meal, to all lunch provided (and some other combinations). The deciding factor was usually size: smaller conferences usually provide more food. But, while I enjoy "free" food, I tend to go to conferences to hear about cool new research, meet interesting people, not primarily to eat.

@feynman Are you sure the conference you're looking at isn't predatory?

@JoeyEremondi not at all there are many like these

@AzorAhai-him-  Mathematical, physical, engineering sciences. Usually math charges less or no money

I think the distinction is much more about the size of a meeting...workshop...conference...congress than about what country that might be in.

@feynman Not saying that conferences don't have fees, but a conference that doesn't get you anything for those fees (e.g. no food)

As I wrote in a comment, a lot of generalisations in this question make no sense to me and are inconsistent with my (fairly extensive, by now) experience attending conferences.

Most conferences do expect advance registration, but this is simply a necessity of conference planning rather than an attempt to extract more value. It's impossible to organise a conference if you don't know whether you will have 50 or 150 attendees. This is not only true for conferences in Europe, but everywhere in the world.
Similarly, I am not sure I have ever attended a conference that did not offer at least basic catering as part of the registration fee (often bad catering, granted, but this was again not correlated to where the conference was hosted).
It may well be that conferences in Europe are expensive in comparison to some other locations (e.g., in Asia), but this is simply because the price level in Europe also tends to be fairly high. It's more expensive to rent rooms, pay the salary of technicians, and buy food in Europe than it is in India.

In any case, (scientific) conferences are basically never for-profit. The budget is usually configured to make a small profit, which then goes to some umbrella organisation (e.g., IEEE) in exchange for insurance in case the conference makes a loss (which does sometimes happen). There isn't really any incentive for the conference organisers to maximise this profit - as long as it's above 0, everybody in the organisation team is roughly equally happy. They do not get to keep the spoils of a particularly (financially) successful edition anyway.
Of course, people can and do have discussions about how to specifically configure the budget within the constraints of aiming for a black zero plus epsilon. Do you want minimal expenses and minimal registration fees, or do you want the conference to be a more lavish experience (with a higher price tag)? Or do you want more expensive registrations for senior members to support cheap student registrations? These are all fair questions, but they are, again, not particularly location-dependent.
If you see differences in pricing, I suspect one of two things will be the reason:

Differences in price level of the hosting country. As I said above, some countries are just a lot more expensive than others. Conference tickets will reflect this, at least to a degree.
Differences in price level based on the size of the conference. Strangely enough, there is a "diseconomies of scale" effect for conferences - they get more expensive to do the larger they get. Small workshops can be organised almost for free, and it's often possible to do them without asking for any registration fee. For a smaller conference (say, 100 participants), you can still do them cheaply. You can often use cheap university halls, you have lots of options for catering and can select a low-cost one, and one or two industrial sponsors may account for a significant part of the costs. For a large conference (say, 2000 participants), the per-person costs skyrocket - there may only be one or two options in your city where you can even physically host your event, and they are going to make you pay dearly for the privilege. Same for catering - if you have any choice at all, the choices will be limited, and none of them will be particularly cheap. Sponsorships you can attract will now mostly be a drop in the bucket for your event. Since your entire budget is much larger, you need to aim for a higher profit since otherwise even a few percent less income may be financially disastrous for the hosting organisation. You now need the support from a professional event planner, and they do not work for free. You need to cover your liability with insurances, etc. In short, you have lots of costs that do not come up with smaller events. Registrations need to pay for these costs.


As an example, I recently came back from the RNA society meeting at the Edinburgh conference centre. Prices for this start at £40 per delegate per day, but this is only for the use of one of the 16 spaces. This conference used 10 of those spaces and was for 5 days. Those prices don't include any catering.

@IanSudbery I assume you mean this as an example of a conference without catering? Because 40 pounds per day seems very cheap for what I assume to be a large event?

This is what the EICC charged the RNA society just for venue hire (and if guess it was at least twice that - £40 a head isbthe cheapest package with only one room, not 10). The conference in total was £1200, but included some catering.

Non-profit management is a career like any other; managers of non-profits get paid for what they do for the finances of the non-profit they work for, and get their next job based on their past success. So, at the level of the actual people making these decisions, with the exception of smaller societies run directly by academics, those are the incentives.

Especially for small conferences (say 20 to 50 people) there are also large differences in what the host university offers or charges for. Often lecture halls are free but there are cases where the professor/ department hosting the conference have to pay the university to use them. At the other end, some universities may throw in some catering for free or a reduced rate deal for local hotels if you organise a conference there. At that end there may be cultural differences between countries.

@BryanKrause I have been involved in the organisation of four small to medium sized conferences, under the umbrella of IEEE or ACM. Not once have I even met somebody from these organisations aside from a handful of emails. It may be true that they would prefer conferences to be (more) profitable, but they have absolutely no impact on any organisational decisions that me or other chairs take. I do not work for IEEE or ACM, there are few things I care less about as a conference chair than their bottom line.

@xLeitix That's a pretty different (non-profit) business model than when the non-profit itself is running the conference.

@BryanKrause This may be, but at least in CS I am struggling to think of a single well-reputed academic conference that's run by an organisation, and not by volunteers (professors) which change yearly. Things may be different in the life sciences, though.

I'm curious what field you're in, 2,000 is not particularly "large" to me (for a "conference").

@AzorAhai-him- Software engineering. I understand that conferences in other fields can be much larger (and much smaller in others). That said, I don't think it truly matters that much. Even with "only" 1000 - 2000 people you already need a large conference or exhibition hall and professional support, similar to a 5000 people event. You can't run it the same way as a 150 person event.

@xLeitix for sure. I was just curious.

To add to the size considerations, there is also the question of salaries. For a small, single room workshop organized locally at some university, there is generally no need to hire any additional helpers. Even the catering could be a store bought cake and coffee from the department's coffee machine, arranged by the local secretary. Of course effectively everyone is still paid, just not from a conference related source of money.

@xLeitix - In the parts of life-sciences I am accusomed to, conferences are organised by the societies themselves directly. However "the socieites directly" is still a bunch of academics, as the societies are generally run by academics, with perhaps a small number of paid administrative assistants. That may well be different for something like the American Society of Human Genetics (ASHG), whose conferences have ~8,000 delegates, and plenaries take place in stadiums.

You list all the reasons why larger conferences are more expensive (which matches my experience), so I'm a bit puzzled why you still describe this as strange.  And if conferences get truly huge, then the conference itself will drive hotel prices up.

@gerrit Most stuff gets cheaper per person the more people you can distribute the fixed costs over. I find it counter-intuitive that that's really not true for conferences.

As a former Executive Chair and Finance Chair for an IEEE conference, I can say that there's no rules to this, and it will often depend on the venue.  My experiences are in USA/Asia, not that EU, and we generally just try to break even and it's often far from a money making proposition.  We had a conference where "the mouse" is and we back calculated that it was 7USD per cup of coffee, which is quite the surprise.   We generally discount early registrations so we can get a head count for the venue, and also food is never included unless you want to pay to go to a networking dinner.  I do generally try to get a budget to pay for undergraduate student travel, but that largely depends on how much the venue will cost.
As far as cultural dynamics, we would never expect to feed anyone outside of some pastries, coffee, and tea.

It is interesting that the labour cost in the usa is also as high as in the eu, but the former just makes even

One thing that hasn't been mentioned (at least not explicitly) is demand management, and holding people to their registrations.
In my field conferences, the number of people that can fit in the venues is limited, and they often fill up or "sell out", as it were. For many conferences that open registriations 2-3 months before the conference, they will fill up within a week of opening registrations. If some one registers, and then doesn;t turn up, they deny some one else, who may have turned up, that space.  Making people pay up front is a good way to ensure that if some one registers, they will definately turn up.

In my field, the cheapest conferences are small to mid-sized, society-organised conferences that are hosted by universities and don't include meals. These are sometimes not well run and the facilities are not always ideal, with parallel sessions being held in different buildings.
University-hosted conferences that do include meals are usually a little more expensive.
Conferences involving more than a couple of hundred participants don't work well without proper convention centre facilities, so they usually cost more. If meals are included (which most do), it's a little more again. If the conference dinner or a field trip on the side are included in the registration, that adds to the cost, too (but means that participants can get their employers to pay for these perks). If the conference is not organised by volunteers through a society, but by a professional event management company, that adds significantly to the cost. Event-management company conferences are sometimes legitimate, but sometimes predatory, so make sure you know the good conferences in your field.

Well, what I really don't understand is why anybody would choose to go to a conference with a registration fee in the first place unless he or she is desperate in their job search or have an insatiable lust for publicity. The old hospitality rule which predates the recorded history is that the host pays all invited guest expenses. If you cannot do it, don't organize a meeting in the first place.
We have been running a small 2-day conference at Kent State (Informal Analysis Seminar; about 30 to 60 participants) for a number of years and we have never required any "registration fees". Moreover, we provided all participants with free lunch, the end of conference dinner, paid all expenses and occasionally a honorarium to the invited speakers and lodging and transportation to a noticeable part of participants. Granted, the lunch was not ordered from the best restaurant in Barcelona with overnight air delivery and we made tea and coffee ourselves in big pots, but we have managed to stay within our resources, so it is possible if you really want it. For bigger conferences, one is not, of course, obliged to pay the expenses to people who came without invitation, but if somebody invites me as a speaker and tells me that I should pay for my trip, lodging  and meals myself (forget about the registration fee!), I consider it as a direct insult and usually do not bother even to respond to such an outlandish offer.
Of course, the current culture is different, but I find trying to live by the old rules that predate the so called "modern civilization" to make more sense than trying to adjust to the latest cultural and political fads that rotate like a weathervane in a tempest.
Just my two cents, as usual. Feel free to downvote :-)

"Well, what I really don't understand is why anybody would choose to go to a conference with a registration fee in the first place unless he or she is desperate in their job search or have an insatiable lust for publicity." This appears to be highly field dependent- all the major conferences in mine have at least a (nominal) fee to cover costs, and have for decades.

"unless he or she is desperate in their job search or have an insatiable lust for publicity." You seem to be an expert in other people motivations and other fields conventions.
